# application running fine on winXP and not on win7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

I have an application written in C# and built using Visual Studio 2005 on winXP. It is working fine on winXP. If i try to run it on win7, I am getting an error called ".NET Framework Initialization Error." "Unable to find a version of the run time to run this application." Application target framework is .Net 2.0. How can i make it run on win7 ?

Comment: change project settings to target framework 4 or 4.5, rebuild. or install framework 2

Comment: I already have framework 2 installed on my PC. Can we change the target framework in VS2005 to 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the files properties and go to compatibility then click on run in compatibility mode and then click on windows xp. this should fix the problem.

here's a screenshot to help. Ignore the fact that the options are blanked out they shouldn't be on yours.
[image: here's a screenshot to help.]

Comment: I could not find compatibility under properties. Can you please guide me to find compatibility under properties. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the property's and where the compatibility section is.

Answer (score -1):

try to Remove the  .Net framework from your computer and then install .Net framework components through Windows Update .
read it maybe helpful:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/net-framework-initialization-errorunable-to-find-a/6ef76069-f481-48ad-ac30-d03e5c4d9638